# I found physics quite interesting <to study>

Tags: grammar, american-english

I am wondering if I **omit "to study"** from the following sentence, will it harm the sentence structure or will it make the sentence incorrect:

" I found physics  interesting **to study** " to " I found physics interesting "

my context is, I have written a short paragraph on my college education then I am thinking of putting this line that **I found physics interesting or very interesting**. So, can I omit "to study" in this context???

any suggestions please.....

Comment: Yes, you can omit it if that is clear  The reader may need to look to see if you are talking about just coursework or more (e.g., you had a summer internship in the field).  You might look for an adjective other than the overused *interesting*. If something is *very interesting*, perhaps it rises to *fascinating* or *intriguing* or it *captured you imagination*.

Comment: Thank you sir....

Comment: The odd adjective involved in tough-movement (It is tough to study physics ↔ Physics is tough [to study]) mustn't drop the to-infinitival complement (That poodle was nice [to eat]).

Comment: " I found the study of physics quite interesting "

Comment: You could also use *physics course(s)* or a course name *Applied Physics*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *That poodle was tough [to eat/train]*

Comment: Well, there are people who study the science of learning, in which case I guess the two might have a different meaning - I could be interested in the process of learning physics without caring much about the subject.  Other than that strange case, the two are virtually the same.  For a resume, I would think I would go with "I found physics interesting".  It opens the door for someone to ask you in an interview why you found it interesting and you can doubtless regale her with "When I studied physics, I...".  Agree with @DjinTonic that "interesting" is a bit, well, uninteresting!